# Step by step on how I should update/upgrade Zookeeper

Tags: upgrade, updates, apache-zookeeper

I have a setup for Apache Solr 7.4.0 for which I currently use Zookeeper 3.4.13. From what I have been experiencing and what I have read, an upgrade may be in order.

I had previously installed Zookeeper through the instructions I had gleaned on Stack Overflow.

Could anyone tell me how this may be done, preferably in a step by step fashion?

I can stop Zookeeper and all Solr servers to accomplish this.

Comment: What version are you upgrading to?

Comment: I was hoping to upgrade to a later version of Zookeeper, but have realised that I already have the latest version. Suppose that in the future, I plan to upgrade to a newer version of Zookeeper, how should I accomplish this?

Comment: I think this answer is a very good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245599/what-do-i-need-to-know-when-upgrading-zookeeper-from-3-3-x-to-3-4-x

Comment: Thank you fro your solution. I have since identified and fixed other errors responsible for the issue and am running without any issues